# How can I generate a mask on a solid or create a custom (complex) drawing on that solid to Adobe After Effects only via scripting

Tags: adobe, extendscript, after-effects

I'm making an After Effects script that generates simple shapes & animations for kids, and I'm trying to avoid importing vector shapes from Illustrator to After Effects to animate them. And that is working perfectly with simple shapes such as squares and circles.

Is there any solution for generating complex shapes inside the Extendscript Toolkit, a pure code with no imports or locating some .txt file, just by setting the vertices, position and color of the shape and applies it to a new solid as a mask by running the script inside of After Effects?

If I wanted to do it manually, I will add a new solid, copy the first path from Illustrator, and back to after effects to paste it on that solid,then I'll add another solid, back to illustrator, copy another path, back to after effect, paste it on solid 2, and I'll repeat the process till the final result appears.

I want to end this switching between software 1 and 2 and save the drawing as an array of [vertices], [in-tangents], and [out-tangents] and call it whenever I want!

[Running the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jX6d6.png)
[The Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzYWt.png)

Answer (score 1):

I've done it like this, it can be used for import any kind of footage

```
var path = "File Path";

 var input = new ImportOptinputns(File(path));
 if (input.canImportAs(ImportAsType.FOOTAGE));
     input.importAs = ImportAsType.FOOTAGE;
```

Or if you want to import an image sequence you can do it like this

```
// or if your footage is an image sequence             
     input.sequence = true;
     input.forceAlphabetical = true;

     imageSequence = app.project.importFile(input);    
     imageSequence.name = 'My automatically imported foorage";

     theComp = app.project.activeItem;  //import in to currently selected composition
     theComp.layers.add(imageSequence);
```

Comment: I was asking if there's a way to avoid importing, not how to import. And I'm not talking about images, I need to draw vectors by coding it (same way when you use the pen tool on a solid to draw a mask).

Comment: My mistake but you really need to fix your question, "How can I import a vector to Adobe After Effects only via scripting"
It clearly asks for import vector into after effect via script!
Sorry if I get it wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry about that, that was the mistake. thanks for alerting me

Answer (score 0):

I know how to create simple vector objects via script but I'm not sure if its work for you as you want it.
An example of two group rectangle

```
var shapeLayer = newComp.layers.addShape(); // adding shape layer    
        shapeLayer.name = "bannerLayer"; // name the shape layer
var shapeGroup1 = shapeLayer.property("Contents").addProperty("ADBE Vector Group"); / creating a group1
        shapeGroup1.name = "Banner"; //name the group1
        myRect= shapeGroup1.property("Contents").addProperty("ADBE Vector Shape - Rect"); // adding rectangle to the group1
```

Another example of a more complex shape, a triangle add to an existing shape layer, you can use this code as a base and create more complex shapes.

```
var shapeLayer = newComp.layers.addShape(); // adding shape layer    
shapeLayer.name = "bannerLayer"; // name the shape layer
var shapeGroup1 = shapeLayer.property("Contents").addProperty("ADBE Vector Group"); // creating a group1
shapeGroup1.name = "Banner"; //name the group1
myRect = shapeGroup1.property("Contents").addProperty("ADBE Vector Shape - Rect"); // adding rectangle to the group1

// construct a Shape object that forms a triangle
var myTriShape = new Shape();
myTriShape.vertices = [[-50,50], [50,50], [0,100]];
myTriShape.closed = true;

// add a Path group to our existing shape layer
myTriGroup = shapeLayer.property("Contents").addProperty("ADBE Vector Group"); // adding rectangle to the group1
myTriGroup.name = "Triangle";
myTri = myTriGroup.property("Contents").addProperty("ADBE Vector Shape - Group");

// set the Path property in the group to our triangle shape
myTri.property("Path").setValue(myTriShape);
```

you can find more information on this page. I googled it myself.

Check this link https://forums.creativecow.net/docs/forums/post.php?forumid=2&postid=1119306&univpostid=1119306&pview=t

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really appreciate it. we are almost coming close to my point which I hope to say it in a more obvious way.
This line:
myTriShape.vertices = [[-50,50], [50,50], [0,100]];
how should I know the exact numbers of this array when I draw something complex on Adobe Illustrator? I did a search on google and I didn't find anything close.
Thanks again

Comment: Glad to help. This point its basically the pixel positions.
That means you need to address all of the points one by one after each other.
As this point is the base of you the composite dimension, The best solution to find the exact location of each point is to create a project in Photoshop or Illustrator with the exact size of your project composite width and height and check all of the point position with roller tools.
if it's not clear just let me know.